# Declaring an array in a loop

Tags: arrays, loops, c++-cli, declaration

Is it possible to declare an array inside a loop. For some reasons I can not declare it before the loop since its length changes. I am wondering if I can re-declare/delete an array within the loop. I am using C++/CLI language.

Comment: could you please show us the code. So we can better understand the problem

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want to know. You can declare (define) an array inside a loop, but you won't be able to use it anywhere outside the loop. You could also declare the array outside the loop and create it (eg. by calling new ...) inside the loop, in which case you would be able to use it anywhere as far as the scope the declaration is in goes.

Comment: My code is about 1000 lines so far. Let me ask my question in another form. Can I change the row number of a declared array? I am gonna declare an array before a for loop and change rows number in each loop.

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: I do not know how to call new. I am just using basics of C++/CLI :-(

Comment: a very simple example is apprciated

Comment: How can I change this array so that I can use it in an array. Luck changes in each loop.                                       array<int>^ Blt = gcnew array<int>(Luck);

Answer (score 0):

Native c++ arrays, must have their size determined at compile-time if they are allocated on the stack, and so if you want to use native arrays, you'll have to allocate them with the `new` operator.

**Unrecommended solution:**

```
int rows = 1000;
int arr[] = new int[rows]; //new array with 1000 integers
int rows = 5;
delete arr; //don't forget to delete the previous allocation before re-sizing
int arr[] = new int[rows]; //new array with 5 integers
```

This however forces you to constantly be aware of allocations and de-allocations. That's why the standard and Microsoft gave you `std::vector` and `cli::array`.

**The Managed way:**

If you want your array to be on the managed heap, use `cli::array:`

```
cli::array<int> ^arr= gcnew cli::array<int>(1000); //new array with 1000 integers
Array::Resize(arr, 5); //resize arr to 5 integers
```

**The unmanaged way:**

If you want your array to be on the unmanaged heap (native C++), use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> arr(1000); //new array with 1000 integers
arr.resize(5); //resize array to 5 integers
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array::Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) method in each iteration (as eladidan says); or you could use a [List<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class, add items in each iteration and finally call List<>::ToArray() to get the array you are looking for. Probably the first way would be more efficient but the second one is more convenient.